# Maven <include> wildcard match on partial folder name

Tags: maven, maven-3, wildcard

With the maven-clean-plugin I would like to remove all folders that start with "tmp". Is this possbile with maven wildcards? I have tried:

```
<fileset>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/tmp*</include>
    </includes>
</fileset>
```

Which does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This configuration works for me:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/tmp*/</include>
                </includes>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I add these folders in the project root:

```
some/tmp/
some/tmpFolder/
some/realFolder/
```

Then the `mvn clean` will delete the first two folders and leave the last one.

Comment: Very interesting, the folders created have the format of tmp[number] e.g: "tmp245343". "tmpFolder" and "tmpfolder" are removed using that configuration, but tmp[number] is not.

Comment: `tmp123` works for me. What OS are you running on? I am on Windows 7.

Comment: Add `<verbose>true</verbose>` in the configuration.