# How to use real jar names in manifest classpath using maven-jar-plugin/maven-war-plugin

Tags: version, classpath, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

For some reason my client needs my artifacts *without* version in their names (`MyArtifact.jar` instead of `MyArtifact-1.23.345.jar`)

Therefor I added this configuration to my parent pom:

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

This works as expected, meaning that I get jars of the child projects without versions generated in `target` folder.

---

However.

One of my jars is an *executable jar* which depends on the others. Currently I have the `maven-jar-plugin` configured for that subproject:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-classpath</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <fileSeparator>/</fileSeparator>
                <pathSeparator>;</pathSeparator>
                <outputProperty>bundle.classPath</outputProperty>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>${bundle.classPath}</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem is that this generated classpath contains *absolute paths* to the artifacts on my PC.

Therefore I added the `<prefix>` tag to the configuration:

```
            <configuration>
                <prefix>lib</prefix>
                <fileSeparator>/</fileSeparator>
                <pathSeparator>;</pathSeparator>
                <outputProperty>bundle.classPath</outputProperty>
            </configuration>
```

But then the generated classpath *includes* the version numbers of the jars.

> How can I omit the version numbers **and** the absolute paths in the classpath?

Problem is: I only want to remove Version numbers from **my own** artifacts, not from third party libs.

Comment: So you want to keep the version number, but want the path to be different so the client can get your plugins and only from your own artifacts?

Comment: @KingReload: Not quite: I want *no* path and *not* version number for *my own* artifacts (sub projects of the maven build) but I need to keep the version number on third party dependencies. Therefore I cannot use a regexp based solution...

Comment: that's why you tried to use `<finalName>`?

Comment: @KingReload yes.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the version from copied dependencies, you can use the [stripVersion](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#stripVersion) option of the `maven-dependency-plugin`.

1. In the aggregator pom use the `dependency:copy-dependencies` to copy your `jars` to some intermediate location.
2. For you internal dependencies use `<stripVersion>true</stripVersion>`.
3. For you 3rd party libraries use `<stripVersion>false</stripVersion>`.
4. You may in-/exclude artifacts based on the group id.

For more detail you may look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

EDIT:

This is to explain how the `finalname` works.

```
finalName: This is the name of the bundled project when it is finally built 
(sans the file extension, for example: my-project-1.0.jar). It defaults to 
${artifactId}-${version}. The term "finalName" is kind of a misnomer, 
however, as plugins that build the bundled project have every right to 
ignore/modify this name (but they usually do NOT). For example, if the 
maven-jar-plugin is configured to give a jar a classifier of test, then the 
actual jar defined above will be built as my-project-1.0-test.jar.
```

Basically it includes almost always the version in your `.jar`.

In the version (2.6 >), in the `<configuration>` it allows you to specify the `<fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>`.

Comment: *"For you internal dependencies use <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>.
For you 3rd party libraries use <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>."* I know how to define the group ID for my artifacts, but how do I configure the group ID in my POM for *all except my*?

Comment: Except your 3rd party? Or what do you mean, as you stopped at `except my?`??

Comment: to match the external libs I would like to use a *wild card* excluding my own jars by their groupId.

Comment: When `<include>` subelements are present, they define a set of project coordinates to include. If none is present, then `<includes>` represents all valid values. Artifact coordinates may be given in simple `groupId:artifactId` form, or they may be fully qualified in the form `groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version`. Additionally, wildcards can be used, as in `*:maven-*`

Comment: Could you please copy the POM from my Quesston and enhance it with an example in your answer?

Comment: You could also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13288677/7707749 to understand how to implement a wildcard

Comment: this other answer has wildcarts for the folders, not for the goupIds...

Comment: Currently I'm helping from my phone, so I can't do much, I do understand what you're saying now, as I was a bit confused of what you meant before. Maybe you could try to look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/7556707/7707749 for group id's and wildcards. I hope this could help you out better then my last link.

Comment: I really apprechiate your effords, but those links refer to diffrent plugins/POM-parts, so I would really like to see an example suitable for my problem...

Comment: Sadly I can't provide you of an example right now, as I dont have my computer near :( I hope your problem will be solved anyway! I am very curious in what way you mean to use the wildcard / groupid

Answer (score 1):

The jar plugin alone is able to compute and write the manifest classpath.
This produces a working jar with the desired name

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned in the Question: the resulting classpath contains version numbers for all jars, even the jars of my own subprojects that have exactly this configuration (`<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>`) in their POM. This is the problem.