# Maven surefire plugin doesn't find unit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

- Yes, the Java classes which are containing the tests are named correctly. (they are ending with Tests)
- Tried to add the following configuration in pom.xml:

```
     <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
```

- Tests are located under the following structure: /src/test/*packagename*/JavaClassTest.java where *packagename* is the same package what is under the unit test written under src/main/java path.
- I'm using jupiter Junit 5 and maven-surefire-plugin with 2.22.2

And I still get the following error on mvn test:

```
    --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ <project-name> ---
    [INFO] No tests to run.
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You miss the *java* folder after *src/test*

Comment: when I tried to add java folder then I lost the visibility of the package private methods/variables. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: _"they are ending with Tests"_, that right there could be your problem, because the pattern looks for classes ending in `Test`, not `Test**s**`. And as Jens says, make sure that your layout follows Maven conventions. Java test should normally be in `src/test/java`, not `src/test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you configure just a certain tests? By default the surefire plugin should access all classes in testRoot and sub directories.

You could also just link a specific file like

src/test/ArchTest.java

to see if it is the "include" in your configuration or something else. I am not sure that the wildecards are working as you expect them to work. See [Maven <include> wildcard match on partial folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288532/maven-include-wildcard-match-on-partial-folder-name) .
Based on this you might try out

```
 <configuration>
      <includes>
          <include>/**/*Test.java</include>
      </includes>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this for junit 5

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.0</version>


           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
               <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.0</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <configuration>
        <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>src/test/java/</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```

add this for junit 4

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```